# Data Structure for finding all bounding boxes that overlap or are contained in a given bounding box

Tags: data-structures, computational-geometry, space-analysis, space-partitioning

I am looking for a data structure that needs to have very fast and accurate queries to solve the following:

The input:
A set of 3 Dimensional axis-aligned bounding boxes B
A separate 3D axis aligned bounding box b'

The output:
A list of bounding boxes from B that overlap or are contained in b'

Traversal time is the most important to me. Construction time and memory usage come next.

Any references or help will be very much appreciated! (I was thinking of a BVH, but i don't know the algorithm for constructing it given the set of bounding boxes. But if there is better data structures for this type of query than a BVH let me know!)

Comment: Do you want the output to include a bounding box in B that contains b'?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: @D.W. I have edited the question to give more information